# AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and iPOD audio playing

Tags: ios, core-audio, avaudioplayer

When I use the play and record category and force the output to the bottom speaker using:

```
    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (   kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker,
                             sizeof (doChangeDefaultRoute),
                             &doChangeDefaultRoute);
```

The audio plays from the bottom speaker but is still much lower in volume when my app is running.  As soon as I shut off my app the volume rises again.  There is no physical change in the volume setting, I can force the audio output to be maximum volume when my app runs and when I shut off my app the volume still becomes louder.

Comment: What values you assigned to `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers` and `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers` properties?

Comment: I enable mixing and leave the duck option as it it.  I also tried setting it to NO as well to see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the issue is with enabling measurement mode for recording audio.  I don't think this is an expected behavior but that was the issue all along.